# Image rotation in IE causes automatic translation. How do I remove the translation?

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, rotation

I'm trying to implement a gauge widget for a website. The spec says only HTML/CSS is allowed, so I can't use JavaScript (don't ask me why -- maybe if there's a *really* simple way of doing it with JavaScript I could persuade the project lead).

So far I have a `div` with a background image that shows the back of the gauge. Inside this div is an `img` that is rotated, depending on the gauge value. This value is dynamically injected into the HTML using PHP.

**The gauge works fine in Safari/FireFox**, but breaks in IE. If I add a border to the image I can see why -- it appears that the IE rotation also includes an automatic translation so that the needle is off-center (see screenshot below).

So, here's the question: how do I shift the needle back to the center of the gauge in IE?

[image: broken needle rotation in internet explorer]

```
<div style="background: url('genies/gauge.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 235px; overflow: hidden;">

<img src="genies/gauge-needle.png" 
 style="-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        transform: rotate(45deg); 
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678118655, M12=-0.70710678118655,M21=0.70710678118655, M22=0.70710678118655, sizingMethod='auto expand'); zoom: 1;" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the image is rotating about a point that you don't expect it to.

You need to set the transform origin to the centre of your image.

For instance, you would use [`-moz-transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform-origin), `-webkit-transform-origin`, `-o-transform-origin`, `-ms-transform-origin`, `-etc-transform-origin`...

Check out this page for information on how to deal with the Matrix filter in MSIE:
https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie

Comment: Ok. So how do I do that in IE? It works fine in FireFox/Safari.

Comment: @jnpcl: yes... for the -`ms-transform`... but for the Matrix filter, it's trickier

Comment: @jnpcl: haha, yep... but when I posted that comment there was only the -moz-transform-origin. Dancrumb edited it after I posted the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be difficult to solve without javascript, if your gauge only moves by a couple of increments (say, 15, 30, 45... deg), you could use this tool:

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

and manually pass the margin-left and margin-top values to IE.

Otherwise I'd recommend javascript with CSSSandPaper by the same author. http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without JS, for IE - [see here](http://balzerg.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/analytical-fix-for-ie-rotation-origin.html)

Comment: Had a quick look -- are you sure you're not using JS? I can see a lot of JS in the fiddle...

Comment: The JS is used to do a pure calculation that you can do on any other browser beforehand or even on the server side. The idea is not having to do the calculation in real time on the IE browser that presents the image